# Emitting multiple States for Single Input using ViewModelType architecture

Tags: rx-swift

Below I have enum representing State of a UITableView.
The states are divided into 3 categories as below.

For all the 3 states I have different UITableViewCells which will be shown for respected cases.

So for fetchMovies input, I am actually checking the movies count and emitting the state & once again after the result.

Can the code written in `transform` be further reduced or any suggestions.

You can find the architecture here [CleanArchitectureRxSwift](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift)

```swift
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

protocol ViewModelType {
  associatedtype Input
  associatedtype Output
  
  func transform(input: Input) -> Output
}

enum MoviesViewModelState {
  case loading
  case loaded([String])
  case loadRemaining
}

class MoviesViewModel: ViewModelType {
  
  deinit {
    print("HomeViewModel deinit")
  }
  
  struct Input {
    let fetchMovies: Driver<Void>
  }
  
  struct Output {
    let movieSection: Driver<MoviesViewModelState>
  }
  
  var repository: SyncRepository
  private var names: [String] = []
  private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
  
  init(repository: SyncRepository) {
    self.repository = repository
  }
  
  func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
    let movieSection = PublishSubject<MoviesViewModelState>()
    
    input.fetchMovies
      .asObservable()
      .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ -> Observable<[String]> in
        if self.names.count > 0 {
          movieSection.onNext(.loadRemaining)
        } else {
          movieSection.onNext(.loading)
        }
        return self.repository.fetchNames(for: self.names.count) // returns Observable<[String]>
    }.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (names: [String]) in
      self.names.append(contentsOf: names)
      movieSection.onNext(.loaded(self.names))
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    return Output(movieSection: movieSection.asDriverOnErrorJustComplete())
  }
}

extension ObservableType {
  func asDriverOnErrorJustComplete() -> Driver<Element> {
    return asDriver { _ in
      return Driver.empty()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the architecture. It's a lot of boilerplate just to implement a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the fact that the result of the network request is needed in the next network request means you have a cycle which mean you have to have a subject of some sort. Also, you have to maintain state which implies a `BahviorSubject` rather than a `PublishSubject`.

That said, whenever you have an `onNext` inside a `subscribe`, there is likely a cleaner way.

```
class MoviesViewModel: ViewModelType {

    struct Input {
        let fetchMovies: Observable<Void>
    }

    struct Output {
        let movieSection: Driver<MoviesViewModelState>
    }

    private let repository: SyncRepository
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(repository: SyncRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let state = BehaviorSubject<[String]>(value: [])

        let movies = input.fetchMovies
            .withLatestFrom(state)
            .share(replay: 1)

        movies
            .map { $0.count }
            .flatMap { [repository] in repository.fetchNames(for: $0) }
            .withLatestFrom(state) { $1 + $0 }
            .bind(to: state)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        return Output(
            movieSection: Observable.merge(
                movies.map { $0.count == 0 ? .loading : .loadRemaining },
                state.map(MoviesViewModelState.loaded)
            ).asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()
        )
    }
}
```

One of the interesting things to note is that the BahviorSubject does *not* need to be a property of the class. The `bind` will capture the subject for you.